# How to extract schema id from avro message in Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming, spark-avro

I have spark Scala dataframe with column contains the value of avro message(Array[Byte]).
I know that the 0 byte is the magic byte and the bytes in positions 1-4 included is the schema id.
how can i extract those bytes (1-4) and add new column with the schema id value in int?

need to use some spark functions/udf in spark Scala to extrace the schema id value

Comment: I suggest creating a standalone example of Scala code with your own `Array[Byte]` of length 5... There's nothing specific to Spark about extracting values from that, then you can start writing a UDF function around that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

// extract the schema id (bytes 1-4) and convert it to integer
val extractSchemaId = udf((message: Array[Byte]) => {
  ByteBuffer.wrap(message.slice(1, 5)).getInt()
})

// assuming the "value" column holds the Avro message
df.withColumn("schema_id", extractSchemaId(df("value")))
```